# Configuração de proxy no java, no sistema Linux

Tags: java, linux, socket

Tenho configuração de proxy em minha rede, e para executar rodar o java preciso setar as propriedades de proxy nele,isso no linux.

No windows não é necessário, ele está funcionando perfeitamente.

> "Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException:
>   homologacao.nfce.fazenda.pr.gov.br
>     atjava.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.(SSLSocketImpl.java:432)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)"

Já configurei no ControlPanel do java, mas não funciona

Answer (score 1):

Seta a configuração do proxy como variável global do SO da seguinte forma:

Proxy sem autenticação:

```
$ export http_proxy="http://PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
$ export https_proxy="https://PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
$ export ftp_proxy="http://PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
```

Proxy com autenticação:

```
$ export http_proxy="http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
$ export https_proxy="https://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
$ export ftp_proxy="http://USER:PASSWORD@PROXY_SERVER:PORT"
```

Caso queira deixar definitivo, só configurar no /etc/profile

Mais detalhes: [Linux Proxy Server Settings – Set Proxy For Command Line](https://www.shellhacks.com/linux-proxy-server-settings-set-proxy-command-line/)